# How do I provide the proper type information to get my generic filter function working for slick

Tags: scala, generics, playframework, playframework-2.2, slick

I'm trying to implement some generic filters in a base class for my slick tables.

What I'm trying to accomplish is the ability to translate url query strings into database filters. I've come up with a working solution, but the code isn't very DRY.

This is my modified code.

```
package db.utils.repos

import common.utils.request.filters.{StringMatchesFilter, RequestFilter}
import scala.slick.lifted.{Column => LiftedColumn}
import db.environments.slick.interfaces.SlickEnv
import org.joda.time.DateTime

import scala.slick.profile.RelationalProfile

trait SlickPageable {

  val slickEnv: SlickEnv

  import slickEnv.profile.simple._

  trait FieldMapped {
    def longField(f: String): Option[LiftedColumn[Long]]

    def optLongField(f: String): Option[LiftedColumn[Option[Long]]]

    def stringField(f: String): Option[LiftedColumn[String]]

    def optStringField(f: String): Option[LiftedColumn[Option[String]]]
  }

  trait FieldSet{
    def stringField(table: FieldMapped, f: String): Option[LiftedColumn[Any]]
  }

  object FSet extends FieldSet {
    override def stringField(table: FieldMapped, f: String): Option[LiftedColumn[String]] = {
      table.stringField(f)
    }

  }

  object OptFSet extends FieldSet {
    override def stringField(table: FieldMapped, f: String): Option[LiftedColumn[Option[String]]] = {
      table.optStringField(f)
    }
  }

  def filter(table: FieldMapped, f: RequestFilter) = {
    queryFilter(table, f, QSet)
  }

  def optFilter(table: FieldMapped, f: RequestFilter) ={
    queryFilter(table, f, OptQSet)
  }


  def queryFilter[T, R](table: FieldMapped, f: RequestFilter, querySet: QuerySet[T, R]) = {
    def checkField[A](field: Option[A], op: (A, String) => R) = {
      field match {
        case Some(fi) =>
          op(fi, f.value)
        case None =>
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"could not retrieve field ${f.field}")
      }
    }
    f match {
      case sf: StringMatchesFilter => {
            checkField(querySet.fSet.stringField(table, f.field), querySet.sEq)
      }
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such filter")
    }
  }

  trait QuerySet[T, R] {
    val fSet: FieldSet
    def sEq(col: T, value: String): R
  }

  object QSet extends QuerySet[LiftedColumn[String], LiftedColumn[Boolean]] {
    override val fSet = FSet
    override def sEq(col: LiftedColumn[String], value: String): LiftedColumn[Boolean] = {
      col === value
    }
  }

  object OptQSet extends QuerySet[LiftedColumn[Option[String]], LiftedColumn[Option[Boolean]]] {
    override val fSet = OptFSet
    override def sEq(col: LiftedColumn[Option[String]], value: String): LiftedColumn[Option[Boolean]] = {
      col === value
    }
  }

}
```

And the error message

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (T, String) => R
[error]  required: (scala.slick.lifted.Column[_], String) => R
[error]             checkField(fieldSet.stringField(table, f.field), querySet.sEq)
```

If I remove the `FieldSet` from the `queryFilter` parameter list I can get it working. But then I need to separate functions: one to call the field mapping methods, and the other to call the optional field mapping methods. It works though, with the type inferencing and everything working properly.

So how can I get this working with `FieldSet`? From what I can tell it seems there isn't enough type information at compile time. But I don't know how to provide it.